# Differentiate between a move, rename and a normal add/delete operation in post-commit hook

Tags: svn, svn-hooks, post-commit-hook

I need to configure a post-commit hook that will identify a rename operation as Rename in the email.

The concern is that we are able to identify them as a Delete & Add operation, but we need to put it up as a single Rename operation.

Same is true with Move operation which is internally treated as Copy / Delete operation.

Any help on which svn property can be exploited for this purpose will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In post-commit hook you have two possibilities

**Choice 1**

Parse output of ordinary `svn log` for commited revision

```
>svn log -v -q -r HEAD
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r3 | Badger | 2014-05-16 10:46:29 +0600 (Пт, 16 май 2014)
Changed paths:
   D /trunk/A.txt
   D /trunk/B.txt
   A /trunk/C.txt (from /trunk/A.txt:2)
   A /trunk/D.txt
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

(here A.txt was renamed into C.txt using `svn mv`, B.txt moved into D.txt using OS-command only)

**Choice 1**

Because it's repository-side operation, use `svnlook` (more compact and noise-free output)

```
>svnlook changed --copy-info z:\Repo
D   trunk/A.txt
D   trunk/B.txt
A + trunk/C.txt
    (from trunk/A.txt:r2)
A   trunk/D.txt
```

Comment: The Choice2, to use svnlook seems to be much better as compared to the first one!